# Breakpoint not set even then it stops here

Tags: c, cvi

I am using Win 10 64 Bit PC with 2012 CVI program to test a function ( as below). The program always stops at this function (MeasurePressureValues) even there is no breakpoint set!

Function:

```
int iRet = 0;
char szDeviceId[200] = "Iso45671A";
double Double1a[4095], Double1b[4095] = {0};
int int1a, int1b= 0;

iRet = MeasurePressureValues(szDeviceId, &int1a, Double1a, &int1b, Double1b, szError);
```

At first call the function MeasurePressureValues() execute and once-again its act as breakpoint to execute same function.

Does anyone face this kind of issue.. what could be the reason

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint set somewhere else?

Comment: Without seeing how this function is defined, it will not be easy to determine why is is blocking.  Include a small compilable sample of the relevant code, and include the definition of this function ([mcve])

Comment: `int1a` is not initialized but passed By Value. This causes Undefined Behavior, possibly the cause of the break.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni: i have delete all my breakpoint and watch expression at my CVI code but still at this function its stop. basically this function MeasurePressureValues() called from Dll which programmed at Visual studio. It dont make sense if we set at breakpoint at Visual Studio at this function, the program stops at CVI. i am struck at this point

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: did you meant to try like this int int1a =0; int  int1b= 0;  to initialise both variable ?

Comment: For example. Or `int 1a=0, 1b=0;`